# Sending GCM notification in chunks

Tags: node.js, algorithm

I want to send GCM notification to 10000 people I will send in chunk of 500 now when I request 1 chunk the response that comes  is message id that to jumbled in sequence how do I make in sequence with request and save

I tried using identifier but the message id is generating randomly I guess so unable to track sequence

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.